# Best way to display list content coming from different site collections in a webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to build a webpart that is going to display list content coming from different site collections (but the same content type).

I wanted to use the SPSiteDataGuery to create the datasource of a SPGridView for instance, but it appears to be working only within the same site collection. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramg/archive/2009/04/22/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart.aspx) where a new `SPSite(url)` is created for each SC to include. Then a query is issued on each site. Clumsy, but it works. Also, feel free to ask on SharePoint Stack Exchange as well.

Comment: Also be careful when writing this kind of code, as the performance is not going to be satisfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best performing solution would be to use the search object model. Look into [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx). You can filter based on content type easily enough. The downside in using this technique is obviously there is a delay until the content is crawled. The performance over anything else however will be significantly better. [Waldek](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/content-query-web-part-vs-custom-aggregation-web-part/) has some great articles on comparing the alternatives.